# Prove that these 3 points are in a straight line.

Tags: geometry, circles

[image]

A triangle ABC is inscribed in a circle $\omega$. $BB_1 $ bisects $\angle ABC$ (and so $M$ is the midpoint of the arc $AC$ ($B \notin AC$, where $AC$ is the arc)). $B_1K \perp BC$ ($K\in\omega$). $BL \perp AK$ ($L \in AC$). Prove that $K,L$ and $M$ are in a straight line.

I've used the letter D to represent those perpendicular angles in the picture (just so that they're easily seen). If you want to hear what I've tried, well, I can see that $\angle LBC = \angle AKB_1$, because $H_1H_2KB$ can be inscribed in another circle. I can't really tell anything more that could possibly be useful for solving this. I'm out of ideas and don't know where to start. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you think $\;H_1H_2KB\;$ can be inscribed in a circle? I can't see, off the top of my head, that this quadrilateral has two *opposite* complementary angles, only two *adyacent* ones...

Comment: $\angle BH_1K = \angle BH_2K \implies H_1T \times TK = H_2T \times TB \implies H_1H_2KB$ can be inscribed in a circle.

Comment: I really don't understand why and how you deduce the above, but it never minds: a quadrilateral with two straight adjacent angles is a rectangle, and I don't think this one's a rectangle.

Comment: Well, I'm not going to show you all the proofs, you can simply find this way of finding out if a quadrilateral can be inscribed here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_quadrilateral. It's written there that "If two lines, one containing segment $AC$ and the other containing segment $BD$, intersect at $X$, then the four points $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$ are concyclic if and only if $AX \times XC = BX \times XD$."

Comment: Oh, I **know** that way of knowing  when it is possible to circumscribe a quad. in a circle. The problem is **how** you deduced that $\;H_1T\cdot TK=H_2T\cdot TB\;$...and besides this you insist in *not* addressing my concern about the **opposite** angles not (or perhaps yes?) summing up to $\;180^\circ\;$, which *at least* should make us doubt...

Comment: It's actually easy to see that $\triangle H_1TB \sim \triangle H_2TK \implies H_1T \cdot TK = H_2T \cdot TB$. And like I said, we don't need to look at anything else when we know that $H_1T \cdot TK = H_2T \cdot TB$ and can say with confidence that the quadrilateral can be in a circle, because, well, the wikipedia article says so, I don't need to prove all that here.

Comment: Well now, *that's* an explanation! Finally.

Comment: @DonAntonio: Here's a simpler explanation: $\angle BH_1K$ is a right angle, so $H_1$ is inscribed in the semi-circle with diameter $\overline{BK}$. Likewise for $H_2$.

Comment: Ah, very nice one, @Blue .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is to prove that $KL$ is the bisect of $\angle AKC$ so it should go through $M$. As you have said $\angle LBC = \angle AKB_1$. So it is enough to prove that $\angle B_1KL = \angle B_1BL$.

$\angle H_1=H_2=90 \land \angle BAK = \angle BCK \to \triangle ABH_1 \sim \triangle CKH_2 \to \frac{BH_1}{AH_1}=\frac{KH_2}{CH_2} \\ \angle H_1=H_2=90 \land \angle KAC = \angle KBC \to
 \triangle ALH_1 \sim \triangle BKH_2 \to \frac{H_1L}{AH_1}=\frac{KH_2}{BH_2} $

Divideing the equalities we will have $\frac{BH_1}{H_1L}=\frac{BH_2}{CH_2}$. So $H_1H_2||B_1L$, therefore we can write:

$\frac{H_1R}{H_2R}=\frac{RL}{RB_1}$

$\triangle BRH_2 \sim \triangle KRH_1 \to \frac{H_1R}{H_2R}=\frac{KR}{BR}$

$\frac{RL}{RB_1}=\frac{H_1R}{H_2R}=\frac{KR}{BR} \land \angle BRB_1=\angle KRL \to \triangle BRB_1\sim \triangle KRL $

Therefore $\angle RBB_1 =\angle RKL $ and this is what we wanted to prove.

[image]

Comment: And thanks for the problem :-)

Comment: Wow. I've thought of an easier one. So we have to prove that $\angle BB_1K = \angle BLK$, which we can do by showing that $BB_1LK$ can be inscribed in a circle. And we can prove this by showing that $\angle LB_1K = \angle KBL$, which we know because $\angle BKA = \angle ACB$ (because $\triangle B_1H_2C$ and $\triangle BH_1K$ are right-angled).

Comment: @mathh Very good, that's really nice.